# How to query pageviews in nodejs @google-analytics/data library

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform

Does anyone know how to query pageviews in the google analytics library for node? Can't seem to find any documentation on which "metric" to query for that:

```
async function runReport() {
  const [response] = await analyticsDataClient.runReport({
    property: `properties/${propertyId}`,
    dimensions: [
      {
        name: 'date',
      },
    ],
    metrics: [
      {
        name: 'pageViews',
      }
    ],
    dateRanges: [
      {
        startDate: '7daysAgo',
        endDate: 'today',
      },
    ],
  });

  console.log('Report result:');
  response.rows.forEach(row => {
    console.log(row.dimensionValues[0], row.metricValues[0]);
  });
}

runReport();
```

Which is giving me an error `Field pageViews is not a valid metric.`

Not sure if anyone is aware of a list that outlines the valid metrics you can query with this library, I wasn't able to find one. I can get the activeUsers just fine so I know the code and configuration is working

Answer (score 0):

Found it about 5 mins after I posted this question - go figure. Hope this helps someone: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/api-schema#metrics

Comment: so.. what is the answer?